# i wan to delete a specific item from an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 9 mc in the stage [a,b,c.....i] , and this `itemIndex[]` content index of every mc , I want to delete a specific item from `itemIndex[]`,  but the problem I find is when I click to the same mc over and over the other items continue to delete from itemIndex[];

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
var myarray: Array = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i];
var itemIndex: Array = [];
for (var j: int = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
    myarray[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto);
    myarray[j].index = j;
    itemIndex.push(j);
}
function goto(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var r = e.target.index;
    itemIndex.splice(e.target.index, 1);// for exemple wen i click to this movieClip with the name a  
                                          //the index of a is 0 ; but 
    trace(itemIndex);
}
//output = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
//         1,2,3,4,5,6,7 
//         1,2,3,4,5,6
//         1,2,3,4,5
//         1,2,3,4
//         1,2,3
//         1,2
//         1
```

Comment: Just unsubscribe the clicked item so it won't invoke the **goto** handler again.

Comment: Alternately, you can check if the given index is still in the list via **Array.indexOf(...)**: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf()

Comment: When you use splice, you are removing the index element, but you are not reindexing the remaining elements. That is, you are changing the positions of the index values stored in itemIndex with each splice. Instead consider doing something more like:  var pos:int = itemIndex.indexOf(e.target.index); itemIndex.removeAt(pos);